# Página não encontrada se coloco parâmetros no final da URL

Tags: facebook, url, http-status-404

Bom dia, estou tendo um problema quando vou postar uma noticia do meu site no facebook, ele adiciona um parâmetro no final da minha URL(www.ex.com/noticia/ex-noticia?**ex=123**). Isso(**ex=123**) faz com que meu site não encontre a página. Estou usando Dotnet alguém tem uma Luz? Obrigado

Comment: Você adiciona o parâmetro na sua URL ou é o código em algum ponto que faz isso? Não ficou claro para mim

Comment: Obrigado pelo comentário Math, o próprio Facebook  que faz isso. Pelo que  eu estava pesquisando ele adiciona o parâmetro **fbclid** devido ao google analytics.

Comment: O que vem depois do "?" são parametros da requisição http, isso por si só não deveria impedir de abrir a página. Qual status code que a requisição retorna?

Comment: Se for algo que possa ajudar outras pessoas poste como resposta, se foi um erro trivial pode falar aqui nos comentários que daí eu fecho a pergunta

Comment: Postei como resposta, acho que pode ajudar alguém. Novamente obrigado pela atenção.

Answer (score 1):

Obrigado pela força Math, consegui corrigir.

A Resolução foi a seguinte. No Web.config:

```
<rewrite url="^/noticias/(\S+)/(\d+)/?$" to="~/noticias/noticia.aspx?codigo=$2&amp;galeria=$3"/>
```

O problema estava no "**$**" que delimitava minha URL amigável. 
Simplesmente retirei ele e funcionou, ficando assim.

```
<rewrite url="^/noticias/(\S+)/(\d+)/?" to="~/noticias/noticia.aspx?codigo=$2&amp;galeria=$3"/>
```